# How to read csv file which has two Seperator and load to excel sheet without losing data?

Tags: python, xml, csv, xpath

I have compared two xml files and printing the output on four different csv files. At the end I have combined all the four csv files into one excel file. But there is a data loss when I perform read_csv. It shows as bad lines.

```
from lxml import etree


Base = etree.parse('Base.xml')
Target = etree.parse('Target.xml')

Base_fullPath = Base.xpath("//Member/@fullPath")
Target_fullPath = Target.xpath("//Member/@fullPath")
Base_name = Base.xpath("//Member/@name")
Target_name = Target.xpath("//Member/@name")

def match(Base_fullPath, Target_fullPath, Base_name,Target_name):
    Base_fullPath_set = set(Base_fullPath)
    Target_fullPath_set = set(Target_fullPath)
    Base_name_set = set(Base_name)
    Target_name_set = set(Target_name)
    if (Base_fullPath_set & Target_fullPath_set,  Base_name_set & Target_name_set):
       x = open('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Common_FullPath.csv', 'w')
       y=(Base_fullPath_set & Target_fullPath_set)
       z=(Base_name_set & Target_name_set)
       print("common details Full Path: \n", *y, sep='\n', file = x)
       print("\n")
       x = open('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Common_name.csv', 'w')
       print("\n common details Name: \n", *z, sep='\n', file=x)
    else:
        print("No Matches Found")
match(Base_fullPath, Target_fullPath, Base_name,Target_name)


def non_match_elements(list_base,list_target):
    non_match_base = []
    non_match_target = []
    for i in list_base:
        if i not in list_target:
            non_match_base.append(i)

    for i in list_target:
            if i not in list_base:
                non_match_target.append(i)
    return non_match_base
    return non_match_target


list_base = Base.xpath("//Member/@*")
list_target = Target.xpath("//Member/@*")

non_match_base = non_match_elements(list_base, list_target)
x = open('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Present_in_base.csv', 'w')
print("\n Base Details: \n", *non_match_base, sep='\n', file = x)
non_match_target = non_match_elements(list_target, list_base)
x = open('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Present_in_target.csv', 'w')
print("\n Target Details: \n", *non_match_target, sep='\n', file = x)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Common_FullPath.csv', delimiter=';;', on_bad_lines = 'skip', engine = 'python')
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Common_name.csv', delimiter=';;', on_bad_lines = 'skip', engine = 'python')
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Present_in_base.csv', delimiter=';;', on_bad_lines = 'skip', engine = 'python' )
df3 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Present_in_target.csv', delimiter=';;', on_bad_lines = 'skip', engine = 'python')

with pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\combined.xlsx") as writer:

    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Common_name", index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="base_Details", index=False)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "target_Details", index=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Full_path", index= False)
```

The above is the code which I have tried.
Please let me know the error.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the results at each stage? What do you mean by data loss? There are some prints when you write the data to files, did you check if the content of the files are ok? Did you check your .csv files to check their sanity before using read_csv?

Comment: If you skip bad lines and you have some, that ends in data lost: on_bad_lines = 'skip'